# JSON.Parse Crashes IOS App

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

In my cordova application (IOS) I am storing JSON object after stringify it in localstorage with the data I receive from a ajax request . But later when I try to use it the app with parse the localstorage item,it is crashing displaying memory warning.

```
localStorage.setItem("mylist", JSON.stringify(mylist));

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mylist"));
```

Is a memory intensive function or what else could be wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: You're setting mysattemptlist and getting mylist. Is that a typo?

Comment: labels you are using to set and get localStorage does not match. May be that is the root cause.

Comment: Thanks that was a mistake in my post. I edited the question with mylist in setitem.

Comment: Before getting any error messages it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

just perform a null check before parsing the item from localStorage to json object.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("mylist")!=null){
var mylist=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mylist"));
}
```

may be you are trying to get the data from localStorage even before setting it.